# syntax error, expecting declaration seen while compiling C code for 8051 microcontroller

Tags: c, 8051

I have a piece of C code in a header file used for a 8051 microcontroller as below -

```
#define Sfr(x, y)       sfr x = y
#define Sbit(x, y, z)   sbit x = y^z
#define Sfr16(x,y)      sfr16 x = y

/*----------------------------------------*/
/* Include file for 8051 SFR Definitions  */
/*----------------------------------------*/

/*  BYTE Register  */

Sfr(P0 , 0x80);      
Sbit (P0_7 , 0x80, 7);
Sbit (P0_6 , 0x80, 6);
```

When compiling, I get the error `line 17: syntax error, expecting declaration`.
Any mistake in the usage of the macro?

Comment: and which is line 17?

Comment: I was just about to ask the same thing.

Comment: are u sure u dont mean y<<z  or y >> z(it looks like you are trying to set up bit masks)

Comment: It is line 17 in another c file that includes this header - #include "REG51xD2.h"

Comment: what is sbit, sfr, sfr16? I suspect you need to include another header

Comment: The 8051 cross compiler offers 3 extensions to the C programming language that allow me to access the SFRs of the 8051. These keywords are:

sbit: For accessing bit-addressable SFRs,
sfr: For accessing byte-addressable SFRs,
sfr16: For accessing 16-bit SFRs.

Comment: but i think you got it for me. these keywords are not being picked up right. will have to find out why. but thanks for the help !

Comment: `^` is the bitwise xor operator. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Each time you use any of your macros, it declares the same variable 'x' over and over.</s>

There's <s>also</s> no evidence that the compiler knows what `sfir` or `sbit` or`sfr16` are.

Comment: so, when i call Sfr(P0, 0x80); will it not substitute simply as sfr P0 = 0x80;

Comment: I dont think u r right 'x' will be replaces by the first macro parameter

Comment: Sorry, yes, you're right about the replacement.  How does the compiler know about `sfr` then?

Comment: so what do you say will get substituted pm100?

Answer (score -1):

a macro must have the '(' immediately after the macro name.  the posted code has a space between the macro name and the '('.  that is why the compiler is expecting a function name.

Also, these macros will not work for all special function registers (SFRs) because many of the registers are affected by reading, so the normal read/modify/write cycle is not acceptable.
For such registers, it is MUCH better to keep an image of the register in RAM. modify the image, then write the whole register. Therefore the SBIT macro cannot be used for all of the special function registers.
there are also restrictions on which opcodes can be used to manipulate bits in the SFRs, again, because of the read/modify/write cycle having undesirable side effects.

Comment: This is incorrect. In a function-like macro *definition*, the `(` must immediately follow the macro name with no whitespace; otherwise the `(` is part of what the macro expands to rather than introducing a parameter list. But there's no such requirement for macro *invocations*. I can define `#define FOO(arg) ...` and then use it as `FOO  ( 42 )` with as much whitespace as I want (even newlines) between `FOO` and `(`. And your second paragraph doesn't address the syntax error, which is what the OP is asking about (it might be good advice though).